# Javascript: force input text inside div to be inside <p> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<div>` element with contenteditable="true" attribute, so I need to write each paragraph that the user will insert inside separate `<p>` element.

I have this div

```
<div class="internal-edit" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Add Question"></div>
```

current inputs wrote like

```
<div class="internal-edit" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Add Question">
Lorem Ipsum
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

and I need to add `<p>` element on input so the final element should be

```
<div class="internal-edit" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Add Question">
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this just vanilla js? No frameworks?

Comment: @GetFuzzy yes just vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? This is over simplified but should get you headed in the right direction. All you need to do  is manipulated the contents of your div by getting the contents and adding to it.

```
var internalEdit = document.getElementsByClassName("internal-edit");
internalEdit.html("<p>" + "Users text here" + "</p>");
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer but I don't think that this will solve the issue as I need to handle the input of the user so I think that I need to listen for input and listen for something like Clicking on Enter button to understand that the user will start a new paragraph and so on